# S4 Validity on ANY slot containing S3 Object

Tags: r, r-s4

Weird error popping up with S4 validity checks.  Seems like S4 is trying to call a validity check on an non-S4 object:

```
setClass("test", slots=c(x="ANY"))
validObject(new("test", x=structure(TRUE, class=c("a"))), complete=TRUE)
# Error in .classEnv(classDef) : 
#  trying to get slot "package" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
```

Compare to:

```
validObject(new("test", x=TRUE), complete=TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Oddly I don't think I used to get this error previously, though I'm not sure what changed.  This is running on R 3.1.2 and I'm almost certain it used to work previously on the same R version.

Comment: `setOldClass("a")` eliminates the error; I'm not sure whether the error is expected or not.

Comment: @MartinMorgan, yes, though separately I'm having conflicts when more than one package declares the same old class, which is why I was using "ANY" in the first place.  I can certainly work around this, but just wondering whether others find this to be unexpected/undesirable (or a feature).